# Python regex with unicode ranges matches characters not in range

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-unicode

I'm using a regex to strip "bullet points" from text. These bullet points are often symbols found in unicode ranges such as geometric shape (\u25a0-\u25ff) or similar. Below is an example of such bullets:

```
 ◉ This is a bullet
 ♦︎ This is also a bullet
 ☉ And so is this

This is not a bullet.
```

I'm using the following regular expression to match these bullet points:

`\s*([\u00a4\u00b7]|[\u2010-\u2017]|[\u2020-\u206f]|[\u2300-\u23f3]|[\u25a0-\u25ff]|[\u2600-\u26ff]|[\u2700-\u27bf]|[\u2b00-\u2bff])\s*`

This works in Ruby (see an example at http://rubular.com/r/O7ZObURmlt), but in Python it matches the first character of any string. For example the `T` character in the string `This is not a bullet` is matched. You can copy the above regex and example text to http://www.pythonregex.com/ to see this for yourselves.

The regex is compiled with the `UNICODE` flag.

How can I make Python's regex engine play nice with this expression?

Comment: Is this is how python is looking at the regex?
     ![Regular expression visualization](https://www.debuggex.com/i/CWCzwK1ZMMRxRKn4.png)

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CWCzwK1ZMMRxRKn4)

Comment: Works for me when I just tried your regex. Please post some code that actually shows the problem you think you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the string that generates your expression be in unicode, so that the sequences are interpreted as unicode characters, instead of plain `u`, `2`, `0`, and so on. Try the following:

```
regex = re.compile(u"\s*([\u00a4\u00b7]|[\u2010-\u2017]|" + \
    "[\u2020-\u206f]|[\u2300-\u23f3]|[\u25a0-\u25ff]|" + \
    "[\u2600-\u26ff]|[\u2700-\u27bf]|[\u2b00-\u2bff])\s*", re.UNICODE)
```

And you're most probably not using Python 3.*, in which all strings are unicode AFAIK.

Comment: Or in other words the range `[0-u]` matches a whole lot of stuff.